# How to swap two if and then statements

Tags: text, expression, notepad++, swap

I have some code to reform (1000 lines) and I want to go from this

```
if $one=0 and $two=32 then $dist=1
if $one=0 and $two=15 then $dist=2
if $one=0 and $two=19 then $dist=3
```

To this

```
if $one=0 and $dist=1 then $two=32
if $one=0 and $dist=2 then $two=15
if $one=0 and $dist=3 then $two=19
```

In a few words swap both $two and its value with $dist and its value.

Can it happen with regular expressions of notepad+?

I tried:

```
if ([^ ]+) and ([^]+) then ([^]+)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\$two=\d+)( then )(\$dist=\d+)`
- Replace with: `$3$2$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\$two=\d+)     : group 1, contains "$two=1 or more digits"
(\s+then\s+)    : group 2, literally "then" surrounded by spaces
(\$dist=\d+)    : group 3, contains "$dist=1 or more digits"
```

`\$` must be escaped because it is a special character in regex.

**Replacement:**

```
$3$2$1   : group 3 group 2 group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
if $one=0 and $dist=1 then $two=32
if $one=0 and $dist=2 then $two=15
if $one=0 and $dist=3 then $two=19
```